# The argument type 'TabBar' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: string, flutter, dart

**Hello Friends, i met an error while putting tabbar into customappbar,**

> It says ,"The argument type 'TabBar' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'String'."

```
// ignore_for_file: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe, unused_import, non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:e_digital_nepal/widgets/custom_appBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'student_leave_card.dart';
import 'student_leave_apply.dart';
import 'datepicker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: StudentLeaveHistory(),
    title: 'Leaves',
  ));
}

class StudentLeaveHistory extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StudentLeaveHistoryState createState() => _StudentLeaveHistoryState();
}

class _StudentLeaveHistoryState extends State<StudentLeaveHistory>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation animation, delayedAnimation, muchDelayedAnimation, LeftCurve;
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));

    delayedAnimation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Interval(0.2, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));

    muchDelayedAnimation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Interval(0.3, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    animationController.forward();
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
```

**now, here is the problem,**

> return DefaultTabController(
> length: 4,
> child: Scaffold(
> appBar: CoustomAppBar(
> title: 'Leaves',
> bottom:TabBar(
> tabs: [
> Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cake)),
> Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.android)),
> Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.phone_android)),
> ],),
> ),

```
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: CoustomAppBar(
              title: 'Leaves',
            bottom:TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cake)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.android)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.phone_android)),
            ],),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(children: [
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                      delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                  child: StudentLeaveHistoryCard(
                    leavetype: 'Cultural & Ritual Ceremony',
                    description:
                        "It is respectfully submitted that, I Subidha Shrestha from class 10 having roll no 15 is suffering from fever since last night. It seems as if that fever is not going away at all, soy father want to rush me to hospital.Therefore I, am unable to attend my school classes for next three days. I hope you will understand my situation will grant me leave for next 03 days.",
                    status: 'Pending',
                    requesteddate: '2078-05-08',
                    verifieddate: '2078-05-09',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                      delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                  child: StudentLeaveHistoryCard(
                    leavetype: 'Cultural & Ritual Ceremony',
                    description:
                        "It is respectfully submitted that, I Subidha Shrestha from class 10 having roll no 15 is suffering from fever since last night. It seems as if that fever is not going away at all, soy father want to rush me to hospital.Therefore I, am unable to attend my school classes for next three days. I hope you will understand my situation will grant me leave for next 03 days.",
                    status: 'Pending',
                    requesteddate: '2078-05-08',
                    verifieddate: '2078-05-09',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                      delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                  child: StudentLeaveHistoryCard(
                    leavetype: 'Cultural & Ritual Ceremony',
                    description:
                        "It is respectfully submitted that, I Subidha Shrestha from class 10 having roll no 15 is suffering from fever since last night. It seems as if that fever is not going away at all, soy father want to rush me to hospital.Therefore I, am unable to attend my school classes for next three days. I hope you will understand my situation will grant me leave for next 03 days.",
                    status: 'Pending',
                    requesteddate: '2078-05-08',
                    verifieddate: '2078-05-09',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                      delayedAnimation.value * width, 0, 0),
                  child: StudentLeaveHistoryCard(
                    leavetype: 'Cultural & Ritual Ceremony',
                    description:
                        "It is respectfully submitted that, I Subidha Shrestha from class 10 having roll no 15 is suffering from fever since last night. It seems as if that fever is not going away at all, soy father want to rush me to hospital.Therefore I, am unable to attend my school classes for next three days. I hope you will understand my situation will grant me leave for next 03 days.",
                    status: 'Pending',
                    requesteddate: '2078-05-08',
                    verifieddate: '2078-05-09',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
              ]),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StudentLeaveApply()),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you create TabBar?

Comment: add custom Appbar code too... so it is easy to debug the error

Comment: I;ve added this,

  final Size preferredSize;
  Color? backgroundColor;
  String bottom;
  String title;
  bool containTabBar;
  TabController? tabController;
  bool isCenterTitle;
  double? elevation;

  CoustomAppBar(
      {Key? key,
      this.backgroundColor,
      this.bottom = '',
      this.title = '',
      this.containTabBar = false,
      this.tabController,
      this.isCenterTitle = false,
      this.elevation})
      : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(containTabBar ? 100.0 : 50.0),
        super(key: key);

Answer (score 0):

I've managed this, @Why_So_Ezz

```
class CoustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  final Size preferredSize;

  Color? backgroundColor;
  String bottom;
  String title;
  bool containTabBar;
  TabController? tabController;
  bool isCenterTitle;
  double? elevation;

  CoustomAppBar(
      {Key? key,
      this.backgroundColor,
      this.bottom = '',
      this.title = '',
      this.containTabBar = false,
      this.tabController,
      this.isCenterTitle = false,
      this.elevation})
      : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(containTabBar ? 100.0 : 50.0),
        super(key: key);
```